# How to create a html page using servlet

Tags: java, database, servlets

I had previously tried to learn java EE. But left it at it seems to be complicated. But then again I decided to learn it by making a small project.The project is very simple ,and I mean to do it to just learn java ee basics.

**What I have done already**

I have a postre SQL database , which stores user details like username,password, email etc.

I have created a registration form using html,when the form is submitted , a servlet gets called which saves the user information in database.

Also I have created the login form , and a servlet which check if the user is authentic or not.

**Now what I want to know**

1) How can I create a page which shows user details , do I need to dynamically generate page for every user.

2) Can I use servlet out.println() to generate the whole webpage, of user details.If this is not the correct way then,how to achieve this.

I don't need any code , I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

## Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

1. *Can I use servlet out.println() to generate the whole webpage, of user details.If this is not the correct way then,how to achieve this.*

You can use Jsp which is advance of servlet.
Servlet has a disadvantage that it do not have a viewport or you have to write a long code like out.print("html"), because of this jsp is introduced.
Jsp page is first converted to servlet and then it is executed.

2. *How can I create a page which shows user details , do I need to dynamically generate page for every user.*

You can create a page using jsp and retrieve user info from database add them to attribute or session attribute and then display it in your jsp page.